# What the difference between cortex-a15 and cortex-a9 in gcc option -mtune?

Tags: gcc, cortex-a

I have a Cortex-A15 board, and compile the program using the -mtune=cortex-a9, I want to know what the difference between cortex-a15, mainly the program performance. And the gcc version is 4.8.3.

Other question: can I use the lmbench or other DMIPS benchmark programs to compare it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what it does on your Cortex-A15 board, why not just compile with -mtune=cortex-a9 and -mtune=cortex-a15 and see the difference?  For your second question, yes you can use LMBench to compare the two, or you can use Dhrystone or CoreMark as DMIPS programs.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling for Cortex-A9 will not generate vfpv4 instructions such as floating point fused multiply-accumulate and idiv.

```
 Features:

 Cortex-A9 : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls   
 Cortex-A15: swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt
```

Read more from my site, for such as Dhrystone, Whetstone and Linpack results in the following, for A15 based system T11 and T11*I, where T11 is from older complier not compiling for later hardware features and T11*I that does via gcc 4.8. My Dhrystone is slower via 4.8 but this is compiling for Android via Eclipse mainly default options.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm